# Accessing NSNumber objects in NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsnumber, nsinteger

I have this:

```
  NSArray *tags =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0],
                       [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1], 
                       [NSNumber numberWithInteger:2],
                       [NSNumber numberWithInteger:3],
                       [NSNumber numberWithInteger:4],
                       [NSNumber numberWithInteger:5],
                       nil];
```

And I'm having a hard time trying to access each item as an `int` or `NSInteger`. What should I do?

Comment: This code could be written shorter in modern objective-C: NSArray *tags = @[@0,@1,@2,@3,@4,@5];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `intValue`

```
NSInteger myInt = [[tags objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
```